# Custom List Calendar View to display Multiple Columns' Data

Tags: custom-list, column, calendar, calculated-column

I am trying to display a custom list in a calendar view. I want to display more then just the title or one of my columns data. I want to show data from a few of the columns, one being a Name. Calculation formula options don't seem to include the name column. Any ideas on how to display more info for my calendar item?

I don't have any admin access so code level changes are not possible. The image below show the one columns selection for multiple day, week and month. I want to add more than one column.

[image: Columns Selection]

Comment: So you say that you don't have admin access. What kind of access? There are a lot of different levels. Do you have access to SP Designer?

Comment: Turns out that I do. I have installed Sharepoint Designer and can do some editing of the code of my pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a calculated column should work for combining most columns into a single column you could use in the calendar view.

However, since you need the Name column, which I assume is a person column which aren't supported in calculated columns, you will need to create a workflow that runs on item creation and updates.

You can use SharePoint designer to create this workflow. It should be set up to  combine all of the information into a single column that you can then use in the calendar view.

Comment: I skipped using the Name and added my Names as categories. Not exactly what I wanted, but it worked. I did create a workflow to concatenate the title and category into another column to display on the calendar overlay.